# Drupal: how execute an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drupal

why in Drupal 7 if i have the following in the hook_menu:

```
 function dash_menu() {
    ...
    ...
    $menuitems['mytest/feed/feedbackid/'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'dash_feedbackid_callback',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
   return $menuitems;
```

}

and in javascript i execute the following:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/mytest/feed/feedbackid/',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    alert('ok')
                },
                // Might want to use 'ui' instead of jQuery('#slider').
                data: 'slider_value=' + '1',
            });
```

in the console i get the following error:

```
POST http://localhost//mytest/feed/feedbackid/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I have reinstalled the module and cleared the cache

Answer (score 0):

Take the first "/" off from url... heres the fixed:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mytest/feed/feedbackid/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                alert('ok')
            },
            // Might want to use 'ui' instead of jQuery('#slider').
            data: 'slider_value=' + '1',
        });
```

Happens to every one off us....